# Move to another Activity from a tab view

Tags: android, android-intent

i created a tab view with three pages in one of the pages i added a list view in that view i added a text view which should move to another activity when clicked but when i create the intent i get a n error and the id of the onClick is never used
the error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method (View)

---

this is the code:

```
package com.halbader.runescape;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


    package com.halbader.runescape;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class QuestsPage extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questspage, container, false);
    return rootView;


}



public void drSlayerQ(View view){
    Intent qIntent = new Intent(this, DragonSlayerQuest.class);
    QuestsPage.this.startActivity(qIntent);
}



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

First bind a proper ID in your Java to your xml element. Then set an OnClickListener and in that, call the function (No need to pass the parameter).

```
public void drSlayerQ(View view){
    Intent qIntent = new Intent(getContext(), DragonSlayerQuest.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(qIntent);
}
```

Comment: TextView moveToQuest1;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questspage, container, false); return rootView;

 moveToQuest1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quest1);
        
 moveToQuest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent qIntent = new Intent(QuestsPage.this, DragonSlayerQuest.class);
  QuestsPage.this.startActivity(qIntent);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Try this as you are moving from fragment to activity :

```
private void moveToNewActivity() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    ((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(0,0);

}
```

Here `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` means no Animation in transition.